# Why is my original folder not kept after compression? Why is my compression so slow? - python 3.4

Tags: python, regex, zip, compression, tar

The purpose of this program is to zip a directory or a folder as simply as possible, and write
         the generated .tar.gz to one of my USB flash drives (or any other location), plans are to add a
         function that will also use 'GnuPG' to encrypt the folder and another
         that will allow user to input a time in order to perform this task
         daily, weekly, monthly, etc. I also want the user to be able to choose
         the destination of the zipped folder. Just wanted to post this up now
         to see if it worked on first attempt and to get a bit of feedback.

My main question is why I lose the main folder upon extraction of the compressed files. For example, if I compress "Documents" which contains the two folders "Videos" and "Pictures" and the file "manual.txt". When I extract the file it does not dump "Documents" into the extraction point it dumps "Videos" and "Pictures" and "manual.txt". Which is fine and  all, no data loss and everything is still intact, just creates a bit of clutter and I would like to keep the original directory.

Also wondering why in the world is this program taking so long to convert the file and when it does the conversion in some cases the .tar.gz file is just as large as the original folder, this happens with video files, it does seem to compress text files well, and much quicker.

Are video files just hard to compress? Or what, It takes like 5 minutes to process 2gb of video files and then they are the same as the original size? Kinda pointless.

Also would it make sense to use regex to validate user input in this case, I could just use a couple if statements instead no? like the preferred input in this program is 'root' not '/root'. Couldn't I just have it cut the '/' off if the input starts with a '/'.

I mainly want to see if this is the right, most efficient way of doing things, I'd rather not be given the answer in the usual stack overflow copy/paste way, lets get a discussion going.

So why is this program so slow when processing larger amounts of data? I expect a reduction in speed but not by that much

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
author: ryan st***
date: 12/5/2015
time: 18:55 Eastern time (GMT -5)
language: python 3.4
'''
# Import, import, import.
import os, subprocess, sys, zipfile, re
import shutil
import time

# Backup (zip) files
def zipDir():

  try:
    # Get file to be zipped and zip file destination from user  
    Dir = "~"

    str1 = input ('Input directory to be zipped(eg. Douments, Dowloads, Desktop/programs): ')
    # an input example that works "bin/mans"
    str2 = input ('Zipped output directory (eg. root, myBackups): ')
    # an output example that works "bin2/test"
    zipName = input ("What would you like to name your zipped folder? ")

    path1 = Dir, str1, "/"
    path2 = Dir, str2, "/"    

   # Zip it up 
   # print (zipFile, ".tar.gz will be created from the folder ", path1[0]+path1[1]+path1[2])
           #"and placed into the folder ", path2[0]+path2[1]+path2[2])   

    zipDirTo = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(path2[0], path2[1]+path2[2], zipName))
    zipDir = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(path1[0], path1[1]))
    print ('Directory "',zipDir,'" will be zipped and saved to the location: "' ,zipDirTo,'.tar.gz"')
    shutil.make_archive(zipDirTo, 'gztar', zipDir)
    print ("file zipped")
  # In Case of mistake 
  except:
    print ("Something went wrong in compression.\n",
    "Ending Task, Please try again")
    quit()

# Execute the program
def main():
    print ("It will be a fucking miracle if this succeeds.")
    zipDir()
    print ("Success!!!!!!")
    time.sleep(2)
    quit()
# Wrap it all up
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Video files are normally compressed themselves and recompressing them doesn't help.for image and video file use tar only.

Comment: Thanks, that explains some things.

Answer (score 1):

> My main question is why I lose the main folder upon extraction of the compressed files

Because you're not storing that folder's name in the zip file. The paths you're using don't include `Documents`, they start with the name of the items inside `Documents`.

> Are video files just hard to compress?

Any file that is already compressed, such as most video and audio formats, will be hard to compress further, and it will take quite a bit of time to find that out if the size is large. You might consider detecting compressed files and storing them in the zip file without further compression using the `ZIP_STORED` constant.

> let[']s get a discussion going.

Stack Overflow's format is not really suited to discussions.

Comment: `ZIP_STORED` could work out for me, thanks for that one. I'll give it a go and see how I like it.

Comment: I'm still having trouble preserving the original filename (documents if zipping documents. I took out the `zipName` variable and did a little adjusting, still can't seem to get it right.